# regular expression pattern

Tags: regex

I want to match this :

- eight(8) alphanumeric characters
- followed by - hyphen
- followed by twentytwo(22) alphanumeric characters, here is what I tried and its not matching :

`[8]\w+-[22]\w+`

Comment: The `[]` define [ **character classes** ](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
\w{8}-\w{22}
```

`[8]` matches a single character - the literal 8, and `[22]` matches one literal 2.

Note that `\w` also allows the underscore. If that is a problem, use

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}
```

A good tip from Tim, if you want tp capture the pattern from a file or string, you probably want to add `\b` - word boundary, to avoid partial matching. For example, if you wanted a 2-4 format `12-1234`, the first parrent will match `12`**`34-1234`**`567`:

```
\b\w{8}-\w{22}\b
```

Comment: almost, except that \w also matches underscores

Comment: +1, and I'd also recommend surrounding everything with `\b` tags just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
\w{8}-\w{22}
```

In most regex languages, \w will match a word character.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `\w{8}-\w{22}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression syntax depends on the language that you use.

[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{22}

Note that \w matches underscores